# Android Studio 1.2 migration?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am following some posts/questions about AndroidStudio-1.2 and it seems that there is a different project structure: `app/src/main`; while my old 1.0 project looked like: `src/main` (no app).

Not sure if this is causing this, but I am not able to get gradle to identify any test files, while running tests.

Comment: Where are your tests in your folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to rename `src/test` to `src/androidTest`.

The app directory is a subproject directory. By default AndroidStudio generate a structure ready for multi-module project. i.e. :

- a root directory with the root build.gradle + gradle.settings (listing all modules in your project)
- a subdirectory (named "app") where you can put all the sources for your application.

Later it is more easy to add a library module (just create a directory myLib in the root folder).

This structure is just proposed by AndroidStudio: you can also use AndroidStudio with only one level of directory and one single build.gradle.